# Not continuous function that is opened but not closed

Tags: general-topology

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68468/example-of-a-non-continuous-function-that-is-open-and-not-closed?rq=1) it is answered that $$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    2x       & \quad \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
    x  & \quad \text{if } \frac{1}{2} < x \leq 1
  \end{cases}$$
is open map but not closed map.

I don't think it is open since $$f((\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4})) = (\frac{1}{2},1] \cup (\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}) = (\frac{1}{2},1] $$

$(\frac{1}{2},1]$ is not an open set.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: But $f\left(\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)\right)=\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, $f\left(\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)\right)=\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)$. I figure you were thinking of $\left(\frac14,\frac34\right)$.

Anyways, notice that the answer says that the map is open as a function from $X$ to $X$, where $X=[0,1]$. So it is talking about openness *in the subspace topologies*, not in $\Bbb R$. Specifically, $\left(\frac12,1\right]$ *is* open in the subspace topology of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of your function is $[ 0, 1]$ so the topology is the relative topology.

Thus a set is open iff it is the intersection of an open set with $[0,1]$.

Similarly a set is 
 closed iff it is the intersection of a closed set with $[0,1]$.